# Use of correct join type in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have two tables as Table-1 and Table -2. I would like to get everything from Table 1 and only the last column from Table -2. My common key is highlighted in the picture. I've tried the following code.Please let me know if it is correct.

```
select t.*,t2.Link_Clicks from t1
left join
t2
on t1.date_start=t2.date
and t1.Adset=t2.Adset
and t1.CampaignName=t2.CampaignName
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. select t.* should be select t1.*
2. when you say "everything from Table 1" are you referring to columns or rows? If columns then you don't need to do left join, inner join should suffice. But if rows, then left join is right.